# chart.js bar chart x-axis label disappeared

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

After resize:

[image: before resize]

Before resize:

[image: after resize]

This is my code. I want to make charts always the same size, but I don't know how.

This is `chart.js` range settings, but I think they are incorrect in this situation.

> Given the number of axis range settings, it is important to understand how they all interact with each other.
>
> The suggestedMax and suggestedMin settings only change the data values that are used to scale the axis. These are useful for extending the range of the axis while maintaining the auto fit behaviour.

```
      /*#######################################*/
      var warnColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
      var careColor = 'rgba(255, 228, 0, 1)';
      var protectColor = 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)';

      Chart.pluginService.register({//PLUG IN
        beforeUpdate: function(chartInstance) {
          chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            dataset.backgroundColor = dataset.data.map(function(data) {
              if ( data >= 70) return warnColor;
              else if ( data >= 50 && data < 70 ) return careColor;
              else return protectColor;
            })
          })
        }
      });

      Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 15;

      var ctx = $('#myChart');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: ["CPU Usage", "Memory Usage", "Network Usage", "Disk Usage", "SysvIPC Count"],
            datasets: [{
              data: [10,20,30,40,50],
              borderColor: [
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          top: 40,
                          bottom: 0
                        }
                      },
                      onClick: barClickEvent,
                      legend: {
                        display: false
                      },
                      scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                          ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100,
                            beginAtZero:true
                          },
                        }]
                      },
                      tooltips: {
                          enabled: true
                      },
                      hover: {
                          animationDuration: 0
                      },
                      animation: {
                          duration: 1,
                          onComplete: function () {
                            var chartInstance = this.chart,
                                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(17, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                    meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                                        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                                        if (index !== 4) {//qnum
                                          data += '%';
                                        }
                                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
        });
        function barClickEvent(event, array){

          var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(event);

          switch (activePoints[0]._index) {
            case 0: window.location = '/usage_cpu';
              break;
            case 1: window.location = '/usage_mem';
              break;
            case 2: window.location = '/usage_tcp';
              break;
            case 3: window.location = '/usage_disk';
              break;
            case 4: window.location = '/stat_ipcq';
              break;
            default: window.location = '/';
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

Old question, but this may be because you have to disable `autoSkip`:

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        beginAtZero: true,
        scaleLabel: {
            labelString: 'Month'
        },
        ticks: {
            autoSkip: false
        }
    }]
}
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration

Comment: The only way this works is inside a 
```javascript

Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('category', {
            gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
                drawOnChartArea: false,
                drawTicks: false
            },
            ticks: {
                // autoSkip: false,
                padding: 20
            },
            maxBarThickness: 10
        });
```
which is inside of what looks like a global config function,  if i add it there it changes globally, and if i add the setting to the individual charts it doesn not work

Answer (score 0):

I was using 
xAxes: [{ ticks: { autoSkip: false } },
        { gridLines: { display: false } }]
and it was failing and as soon as I removed gridLines as 
xAxes: [{ ticks: { autoSkip: false } }
        //{ gridLines: { display: false } }]
it started working: which means combination of property also needs to be consider.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this works is inside a `updateScaleDefaults` function.

```js
Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('category', {
            gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
                drawOnChartArea: false,
                drawTicks: false
            },
            ticks: {
                // autoSkip: false,
                padding: 20
            },
            maxBarThickness: 10
        });
```

which is inside of what looks like a global config function,  if i add it there it changes globally, and if i add the setting to the individual charts it doesn not work